# How to create `authenticate_user' method without devise in ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am new in Ruby on Rails and i am using Ruby version 1.9.3 and Rails version 4.0.2.

My Query is:-

How to create `authenticate_user' method without devise in Ruby on Rails.

**Below my routes**

```
get "admin/users/sign_in" => "admin/users#sign_in"
```

**Below My Application Controller:-**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:alert] = "Access denied. You are not authorized to access the requested page."
    redirect_to root_path and return
  end


  helper_method :current_user
  before_filter :authenticate_user, :current_user

  def current_user
    # Note: we want to use "find_by_id" because it's OK to return a nil.
    # If we were to use User.find, it would throw an exception if the user can't be found.
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_authentication_token(cookies[:auth_token]) if   cookies[:auth_token] && @current_user.nil?
    @current_user
  end

  def authenticate_user
    if @current_user.nil?
      flash[:error] = 'You must be signed in to view that page.'
      redirect_to :admin_users_sign_in

    end
  end


  protected

  #derive the model name from the controller. egs UsersController will return User
  def self.permission
    return name = self.name.gsub('Controller','').singularize.split('::').last.constantize.name rescue nil
  end

  def current_ability
    @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user)
  end

  #load the permissions for the current user so that UI can be manipulated
  def load_permissions
    @current_permissions = current_user.role.permissions.collect{|i| [i.subject_class, i.action]}
  end

end
```

**Below code using my controller**

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

My authenticate_user method not redirect properly

redirect_to :admin_users_sign_in

**admin_users_sign_in** path define in routes see on top

Above the code every time say on browser **"The page isn't redirecting properly"**

Please help

Comment: Perhaps railscasts 250 and 270 could help you

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is due to this line:

```
  redirect_to :admin_users_sign_in
```

You need to pass either an `action` & `controller` or a friendly name of the path to `redirect_to`.

Change your routes to be something like

```
get "admin/users/sign_in" => "admin/users#sign_in", :as => :admin_user_signin
```

Then you can do something like

```
redirect_to admin_user_signin_path
```

Comment: I have use your code. I am using redirect_to admin_user_signin_path this code "The page isn't redirecting properly" display error no browser. if i am using redirect_to :admin_user_signin_path this code "undefined method `admin_user_signin_path_url' for #<Admin::UsersController:0x4edc6f8>" display error in code.

Answer (score 0):

This looks an infinite loop.

You defined `authenticate_user` at ApplicationController level. So, when a visitor visited page 'foo', he is denied by this method because current_user is nil. Then he got redirected to admin sign in page, but that page has this before_filter as well, so he got redirected again, to the same page and never end.

To fix, move such filter to specific controllers which need protection. And do not set it in sign in/sign up page.

Side notes:

You've already used CanCan which has authorization on "read" as well. There is no point to use `authenticate_user` again for same functionality.